# What does Grogu's beskar rondel do?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In season 3, The Armorer creates Grogu a rondel from beskar that has contains embedded circuitry, much like Mandalorian helmets/visors. What function does it have besides being simple armor?

Comment: It lights up and looks cool. Plus it sells toys.

Comment: Advanced amphibian detector?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/119765/circuit-board-on-grogus-rondel